# Jquery disable clicking an element if contents is below 1

Tags: jquery

I have the following divs, when `qc-less` or `qc-more` is clicked, it decreases/increases the number in the `adjustable-count` span.

```
<div class="quantity-counter current-sub">
  <span class="qc-label">Qty</span>
  <span class="qc-less">–</span>
  <span class="qc-count adjustable-count">1</span>
  <span class="qc-more">+</span>
</div>
```

When I click `qc-less`, I don't want the number to go below 1. How can I disable clicking on `qc-less` to stop it going to 0? And enable it again once above 1.

This is what I tried but it's still going to zero:

```
if ($('.adjustable-count:contains("1")').length > 0) {
  $(this).parent().find('.qc-less').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: I think `find('qc-less')` is missing a `.` to search for a class name. But this will also disable `qc-less` when the value is over 9 and under 20, which probably isn't what you intend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some class to your span tag when the quantity is `1` and remove it when it increase . In below i have merge both your event handler and have use `.addClass` and `removeClass` to add/remove class from `qc-less` tag.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".qc-less,.qc-more").click(function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest('.quantity-counter')
  //check if the span click is qc_more 
  $(this).hasClass("qc-more") ? $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text()) + 1) : $(this).next().text(parseInt($(this).next().text()) - 1)
  var text = selector.find('.adjustable-count').text() //get upadted value
  //add/remove disable class
  parseInt(text) <= 1 ? selector.find('.qc-less').addClass("disabled") : selector.find('.qc-less').removeClass("disabled");
})
```

```css
.qc-less,
.qc-more {
  background: blue
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity-counter current-sub">
  <span class="qc-label">Qty</span>
  <span class="qc-less disabled">–</span>
  <span class="qc-count adjustable-count">1</span>
  <span class="qc-more">+</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your work.

---

Here is a working solution. I've done all the incr/decr of the value, since you didn't shared your code.

```js
$('.qc-less').click(function() {
  var value = parseInt($(this).parents('.quantity-counter').find('.qc-count').text());
  value--;
  $(this).parents('.quantity-counter').find('.qc-count').text(value);
  $(this).prop('disabled', value <= 1);
});

$('.qc-more').click(function() {
  var value = parseInt($(this).parents('.quantity-counter').find('.qc-count').text());
  value++;
  $(this).parents('.quantity-counter').find('.qc-count').text(value);
  $(this).parents('.quantity-counter').find('.qc-less').prop('disabled', value <= 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity-counter current-sub">
  <span class="qc-label">Qty</span>
  <button class="qc-less" disabled>–</button>
  <span class="qc-count adjustable-count">1</span>
  <button class="qc-more">+</button>
</div>
```